# How to add samesite=None in the set_cookie function django?

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-views, middleware

I want to add `samesite` attribute as `None` in the `set_cookie function`

This is the code where I call the `set_cookie function`

```
redirect = HttpResponseRedirect( '/m/' )
redirect.set_cookie( 'access_token', access_token, max_age=60 * 60 )
```

This is the function where I set the cookie

```
def set_cookie(self, key, value='', max_age=None, expires=None, path='/',
               domain=None, secure=False, httponly=False):
    self.cookies[key] = value
    if expires is not None:
        if isinstance(expires, datetime.datetime):
            if timezone.is_aware(expires):
                expires = timezone.make_naive(expires, timezone.utc)
            delta = expires - expires.utcnow()
            delta = delta + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
            expires = None
            max_age = max(0, delta.days * 86400 + delta.seconds)
        else:
            self.cookies[key]['expires'] = expires
    else:
        self.cookies[key]['expires'] = ''
    if max_age is not None:
        self.cookies[key]['max-age'] = max_age
        # IE requires expires, so set it if hasn't been already.
        if not expires:
            self.cookies[key]['expires'] = cookie_date(time.time() +
                                                       max_age)
    if path is not None:
        self.cookies[key]['path'] = path
    if domain is not None:
        self.cookies[key]['domain'] = domain
    if secure:
        self.cookies[key]['secure'] = True
    if httponly:
        self.cookies[key]['httponly'] = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library to change the flag if you're using django2.x or older: https://pypi.org/project/django-cookies-samesite/

If you're using django3.x, it should be built-in

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `set_cookie('name', 'value')` on the HTTP response.

Like `return HttpResponse("hi").set_cookie('name', 'Aniket')`

if you are going to use render() then

```
response = render(request,'index.html',data)
response.set_cookie('name','value')
return response
```