# How to set the SameSite attribute of set-cookie in django version 2.0.13?

Tags: python, django, cookies

I installed yangsuite[core], deployed it and called it with an iframe

```
<iframe 
width="700"
    height="800"
src="https://10.225.61.70:7143/netconf/getyang/hangxin+travelsky-set/ietf-interfaces">
</iframe>
```

Here is the view function code
(under the directory lib/python3.8/site-packages/ysnetconf/views/rpc.py):

```
@login_required
def get_yang(request, yangset=None, modulenames=None):
    devices = YSDeviceProfile.list(require_feature="netconf")
    replay_dir = get_path('tasks_dir', user=request.user.username)

    return render(request, 'ysnetconf/netconf.html', {
        'devices': devices,
        'yangset': yangset or '',
        'modulenames': modulenames or '',
        'replay_dir': replay_dir
    })
```

It requires a login, I changed the code to bypass the login(There is some code logic need to access the request.user)

```
# @login_required
def get_yang(request, yangset=None, modulenames=None):
    devices = YSDeviceProfile.list(require_feature="netconf")
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
    user = authenticate(username='admin', password='password')
    login(request, user)
    replay_dir = get_path('tasks_dir', user=request.user.username)

    return render(request, 'ysnetconf/netconf.html', {
        'devices': devices,
        'yangset': yangset or '',
        'modulenames': modulenames or '',
        'replay_dir': replay_dir
    })
```

But when I open the ifram page, a warning suggests I should specify SameSite.
I found a solution, but only in django 2.2.x. Here is the mentioned solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64338648/7004884

I tried to use django-cookies-samesite in 2.0.13, but it didn't work.

In this document (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#) None), it mentions the need to set the secure attribute, which I have done. The cookie I get looks like this

```
Set-Cookie: sessionid=2hm53373qoou4kectdy8lv2z4aqp25y8; expires=Mon, 03-May-2021 05:57:13 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; Secure
```

I think the reason is the version of django.
Is there any other way to set the SameSite property in django version 2.0.13?

Answer (score 9):

1st go to your `settings.py` file and add:

```py
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

it's from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-samesite):

> SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE¶
>
> Default: 'Lax'
>
> The value of the SameSite flag on the session cookie. This flag prevents the cookie from being sent in cross-site requests thus preventing CSRF attacks and making some methods of stealing session cookie impossible.

**`And don't forget SECURE cookie can be used only with HTTPS access`** (django dev server works with HTTP only)

**BUT!**

Using this method is dangerous and can be used for attacks to your site.

So you can try set `samesite='None'` only in views where it's needed (like this):

```py
def login_view(request):
    """Simple login view"""

    user = Users.objects.get(id=1) # Just an
    login(request, use)            # example
    
    response = redirect('/')
    if 'session_id' in response.cookies:
        response.cookies['sessionid']['samesite'] = 'None'
        response.cookies['sessionid']['secure'] = True
    return response
```

This way you don't need to change cookie policy in `settings.py`

P.S. You can set cookie samesite at [creation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie) step:

```py
def index(request):
    response = HttpResponse('Hello world!')
    response.set_cookie(key='name', value='my_value', samesite='None', secure=True)
    return response
```

but don't forget `samesite='None'` at creation step is allowed only in django  3.1+